# How to use npm package ('latlon-geohash') in angular 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the [latlon-geohash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latlon-geohash) npm package in my Angular 7 app, but when I run it, I get this error...

> ERROR TypeError: latlon_geohash__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.encode is
>   not a function

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as gh from 'latlon-geohash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss'],
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
     //Here I'm trying to encode my lat and lng to a GeoHash
    console.log(gh.encode(39.36, -76.69, 4))
  }

}
```

And it doesn't work. However, when I run `console.log(gh)`, I get this...

```
Module {default: ƒ, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
default: class Geohash
adjacent: ƒ adjacent(geohash, direction)
arguments: (...)
bounds: ƒ bounds(geohash)
caller: (...)
decode: ƒ decode(geohash)
encode: ƒ encode(lat, lon, precision) //HERE IS MY FUNCTION
length: 0
name: "Geohash"
neighbours: ƒ neighbours(geohash)
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: latlon-geohash.js:11
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
__esModule: true
__proto__: Object
```

I see my `encode` function right there. Why doesn't it work? I can't seem to find an answer, but I feel like there may be something really simple I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: You should add it to `scripts` array in angular.json.

Comment: But I installed it with `npm install latlon-geohash`. Do I still need to add it there?

Comment: Yes, add the entire path from Node_modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `latlon-geohash` to scripts inside `angular.json`. Any of the 3rd party scripts/libraries need to be made available inside `scripts` in `angular.json`. Provide the full relative path of `latlon-geohash.js` to the angular project so that it becomes available for use.

Make sure you **Rebuild** your project too.

EX:

```
"scripts": [
            "./node_modules/path-to-lib/latlon-geohash.js",
```

Also add the import to your component: `import Geohash from 'latlon-geohash';` as mentioned by Tony.

here is a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8gmiwt) for you to try

Comment: When I added this, I got this error... `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/node_modules/latlon-geohash⁩/latlon-geohash.js'`

Comment: what i meant was: check your `node_modules` folder, find out the path to latlon-geohash, open it go down to the js file available, copy it's path and use that path in scripts inside angular.json.

Comment: It is the right path. I copied and pasted the path into finder, and it went right to the folder.

Comment: did you use `./node_module' and rebuild your project too.

Comment: Ok, so I got it to import (turns out there was an invisible space in the path!?). But I'm still getting the same original error.

Comment: This is the build error I get...
`WARNING in ./src/app/_pages/start/account/account.component.ts 36:20-29
"export 'encode' (imported as 'gh') was not found in 'latlon-geohash'`

Comment: Yeah, in that case try using: `import Geohash from 'latlon-geohash';`

Comment: YES! That worked. Thank you so much! Can you update your answer please and I'll mark it. (Also do me a favor and give @Tony Ngo an upvote)

Comment: Done!. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try these 2 way to see if it work

```
import Geohash from 'latlon-geohash';
```

or

```
const Geohash = require('latlon-geohash')
```

Comment: How is it different from `import * as gh from 'latlon-geohash';`

Comment: It's dffirent because when you use import * you are import whole lib into your component which is not need. We just need to import the instace we want to work with

Comment: since the library has `export default Geohash;`, if you do `import * as gh`, it will work the same way as `import Geohash from 'latlon-geohash';`

Comment: You can use webpack-bundle-analyzer package to see the different in bundle size with 2 syntax import * and normal import

Comment: You were right, thank you for your help. I also had to add it to scripts as mentioned by @nircraft